# Average sales in the Nth month of the customer journey

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x

I need to find average sales by month of the customer. For example one customer bought  in Jan2020 some products... then in Feb... so jan becomes 1st month and feb 2nd for the customer.
Similarly other customer buys 1st time in Apr'20 and next time in June'20..... so avg sales for 1st Mon(Apr) and 2nd month (Avg of Apr and Jun)
Expected outcome:
CustID Month Avg_sales

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of your current implementation, including any specific errors or issues you're facing, and any attempts you've made to solve your problem yourself. This helps the community to give you a more useful and relevant answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions to get the first date.  And then arithmetic.  Here is one method:

```
select custid, year(date) * 12 + month(date) - (year(first_date) * 12 + month(first_date)) as diff,
       avg(sales) as avg_sales
from (select t.*,
             min(date) over (partition by custid) as first_date
      from t
     ) t
group by custid, diff
```